# Flutter would "successfully" download and update but doesn't take effect

Tags: flutter, android-studio, plugins

Using Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8193401, built on February 17, 2022

Every restart it would ask to update the plugin, but soon right after if I check, the version remains the same. Stuck at 63. also did flutter clean, Invalidate Caches, no effect.

[image]

Comment: From android studio File -> Invalid caches -> invalid caches & restart

Comment: @HardikMehta tried it. still stuck

Comment: Do one more thing. android studio -> plugins -> remove flutter then add it again